# Rails 4: Is it a bad practice to do database operations in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Say I have product model(`app/models/product.rb`) and the following method def in the model.

```
def update_stock product
  product.stock -= 1
  product.save(:validation => false)
end
```

Is this acceptable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, it is not bad practice to do database operations in the model. Is this code in `Product`? Does it work? I would expect that it needs `self` instead of `product` (technically, the second probably needs neither)...

Comment: Class methods need to refer with `self` and if so,it is completely acceptable considering the fact `Fat model` and `Skinny controller`.

Comment: This is basically the exact way to do this, by the way, other than it seems like a violation of the law of demeter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and should probably be moved into Product...

Comment: @Brad Werth - The method takes a `product` object, it's not meant to operate on `self`.

Comment: @Max Williams - Yeah, no kidding, that is what I was commenting on. See sevenseacat's answer for how it should be done correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks suspicious to me - you say that this is a method in your Product model, but then the method updates an entirely different product instance (the one you pass in, not the one you call the method on).

If this was something like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update_stock
    self.stock -= 1
    save
  end
end
```

Then it would be much more appropriate. (`update_stock` doesn't seem like the best name for the method, either, and skipping the validations likely isn't a good idea.)

Comment: The method takes a product object.

Comment: Yes I know. Like I said, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good practice to keep the database operations and business logic of an application in model. Model directly interacts with database with ORM (Object Relational mapping). Also in rails convention controller should be thin and model should be fat .This answer explains it in details

[What is Ruby on Rails ORM in layman's terms? Please explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922304/what-is-ruby-on-rails-orm-in-laymans-terms-please-explain)

Answer (score 1):

As you want to update something better use `update_attributes!`

It may be write in this way:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  def update_stock product
   self.update_attributes!(stock:  stock - 1)
 end
end
```

Comment: The method takes a product object!  I can't believe nobody else has noticed this.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you!

The simplest way I use to deduce how to do things is to look at it from a [modular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) perspective. If you have "heavy" code in a controller, **will you benefit from using that code in another area of the app?**

---

**Rails is a series of classes & modules**

Code is accessible to different parts of the app, depending on which modules are called. If you feel like you'll benefit from re-using the method in different areas of the app, you should include either an [instance or class method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) in the model, as this will open this method to those objects

I would use the code provided by `RSB` & `sevenseacat`, probably using the `decrement!` method in `sevenseacat`s answer:

```
self.decrement!(:stock)
```

---

In regards to your question, I would personally do that, but would make it an instance method. `sevenseacat` basically explained what I'd do